# PHP file that's going in an infinite loop

Tags: php, input, infinite-loop

In my game, I implemented a file from [HackingWithPhp](http://www.hackingwithphp.com/21/4/2/text-game-v1) that was originally designed for running on CLI but I tried to port it over to run on html/css/browsers. Aparently, this code goes in an infinite loop, but I can't see why. When I put it on the FTP server my browser crashes when I try to load the page (because php is back-end)... Can anyone tell me why? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the code: (I have `include_once 'index.php';` because I have a textbox input in my main website file and the variable in which the input is stored is on that file, so I need to import it to be able to use it here... If there's any way to put a working text box input in this code too, that would be appreciated.)

```
<?php
include_once 'index.php';
$World = simplexml_load_file("gameworld.xml");
$CurrentPos = 0;
$Done = 0;
print "<br>";
printplace();
function printplace() {
    GLOBAL $World, $CurrentPos;
    $Room = $World->ROOM[$CurrentPos];
    $Name = $Room->NAME;
    $Desc = wordwrap((string)$Room->DESC);
    print "$Name<br>";
    print str_repeat('-', strlen($Name));
    print "<br>$Desc<br>";
    if ((string)$Room->NORTH != '-') {
        $index = (int)$Room->NORTH;
        print "North: {$World->ROOM[$index]->NAME}<br>";
    }
    if ((string)$Room->SOUTH != '-') {
        $index = (int)$Room->SOUTH;
        print "South: {$World->ROOM[$index]->NAME}<br>";
    }
    if ((string)$World->ROOM[$CurrentPos]->WEST != '-') {
        $index = (int)$Room->WEST;
        print "West: {$World->ROOM[$index]->NAME}<br>";
    }
    if ((string)$World->ROOM[$CurrentPos]->EAST != '-') {
        $index = (int)$Room->EAST;
        print "East: {$World->ROOM[$index]->NAME}<br>";
    }
    print "<br>";
}

while (!$Done) {
    print "<br>"; // add another line break after the user input

    $input = split(' ', $input);

    switch(trim($input[0])) {
        case 'north':
            if ((string)$World->ROOM[$CurrentPos]->NORTH != '-') {
                $CurrentPos = (int)$World->ROOM[$CurrentPos]->NORTH;
                printplace() ;
            } else {
                print "You cannot go north!<br>";
            }
            break;
        case 'south':
            if ((string)$World->ROOM[$CurrentPos]->SOUTH != '-') {
                $CurrentPos = (int)$World->ROOM[$CurrentPos]->SOUTH;
                printplace() ;
            } else {
                print "You cannot go south!<br>";
            }
            break;
        case 'west':
            if ((string)$World->ROOM[$CurrentPos]->WEST != '-') {
                $CurrentPos = (int)$World->ROOM[$CurrentPos]->WEST;
                printplace() ;
            } else {
                print "You cannot go west!<br>";
            }
            break;
        case 'east':
            if ((string)$World->ROOM[$CurrentPos]->EAST != '-') {
                $CurrentPos = (int)$World->ROOM[$CurrentPos]->EAST;
                printplace() ;
            } else {
                print "You cannot go east!<br>";
            }
            break;
        case 'look':
            printplace() ;
            break;
        case 'quit':
            $Done = 1;
            break;
    }
}

print "<br>Thanks for playing!<br>";
?>
```

Comment: What is `$input`? I'm thinking it doesn't equal `quit` so `$Done` is never set so `while` keeps looping.

Comment: What is the name of this php file?  I hope it's not index.php.

Comment: The name of this file, thankfully, is game.php :)

Comment: $input is the $_POST textbox input variable from the other php file. I can put that files code on here too, do you want me to?

Comment: if `$input` comes directly from `$_POST` then any invalid string would cause infinite loop (add `case default: break 2;` or sth). What's `split()` for? (deprecated btw.) - you're using only first element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop repeats the same argument over again. You need sth like this I think:

```
$input = explode(' ', $input);
foreach ($input as $command) { //no need for "quit" case or $done flag
    switch ($command) {
        ...
        case default: break; //invalid command (ignore)
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for not understanding, but would you put this in place of `function printplace()` or `switch(trim($input[0]))`?

Comment: Thanks! That got it out of the infinite loop.